# uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError) with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler

When I try to run some rspec test cases I'm getting this error

I'm using linux rails 3.0.0, ruby 1.9.2 (with RVM)

```
config/boot.rb:8: uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' ..
```

But when do a gem list , it shows both
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)

so what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your bundler, in latest version such issue is resolved.

```
'gem install bundler'
```

and then `'bundler install'`

If you find again error, then delete GEM.lock file, then run `bundler install`. It may resolve the issue.