# uninitialized constant Bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

Whenever I try to do `sudo /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle install`, I run into this:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:14: uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
```

Any ideas?

This did not help:

[uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError) with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121962/uninitialized-constant-bundler-nameerror-with-ralis3)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, 64 bit if that helps any.

Comment: Why are you using sudo? You should never use sudo with bundler

Comment: @FrederickCheung it's the system version of ruby/bundler. Don't ask why i'm stuck with it, i just am. :\ EDIT: I'm an idiot, if I don't use sudo that it works.

Comment: Might want to consider using RVM instead.  It's a little easier to avoid gem version collisions with gemsets.

Comment: @Nick a system wide RVM?

Comment: I setup system-wide RVM but I'm not sure I would recommend it unless you share the system with others (or system accounts).

Comment: @Nick situation requires a system-wide (or at least `root`) ruby. do you suggest RVM for that? Nobody else is going to use it.

Comment: This might be worth digging through the SO questions for a (better) answer but I would go with a system-wide install in that case.  I also would recommend creating explicit accounts for apps or Ruby-based processes instead of running them as root.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6448/discussion-between-jrg-and-nick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup a system-wide [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) installation to support separating different Ruby environments (and environments for multiple accounts) on the same system.

Bundler will help in maintaining dependencies for each environment but some gem versions may conflict.  Gemsets within RVM work around that issue by segmenting each environment.